# Why does Twisted think I'm calling request.finish() twice when I am not?

Tags: python, twisted.web

This is an annoying problem I am having with Twisted.web. Basically, I have a class that inherits from `twisted.web.resource.Resource` and adds some default stuff to Mako templates:

```
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
from project.session import SessionData
from project.security import make_nonce


class Page(Resource):

    template = ""

    def display(self, request, **kwargs):
        session = SessionData(request.getSession())

        if self.template:
            templates = TemplateLookup(directories=['templates'])
            template = templates.get_template(self.template)
            return template.render(user=session.user,
                                   info=session.info,
                                   current_path=request.path,
                                   nonce=make_nonce(session),
                                   **kwargs)
        else:
            return ""
```

Then, and I have narrowed the problem down to this small class (which I tested), I write a resource which inherits from `Page`:

```
class Test(pages.Page):
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "<form method='post'><input type='submit'></form>"
    def render_POST(self, request):
        request.redirect("/test")
        request.finish()
```

I'd like to note that, in every other case, if `request.finish()` isn't the last line in a function, then I `return` immediately after it.

Anyways, I add this class to the site at `/test` and when I navigate there, I get a submit button. I click the submit button, and in the console I get:

```
C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\server.py:200: UserWarning: Warning! request.finish called twice.
  self.finish()
```

But, I get this ONLY the first time I submit the page. Every other time, it's fine. I would just ignore this, but it's been nagging at me, and I can't for the life of me figure out why it's doing this at all, and why only the first time the page is submitted. I can't seem to find anything online, and even dropping print statements and tracebacks in the `request.finish()` code didn't reveal anything.

### edit

This morning I tried adding a second `request.finish()` line to the resource, and it still only gave me the error one time. I suppose it will only warn about it in a resource once -- maybe per run of the program, or per session, I'm not sure. In any case, I changed it to:

```
class Test(pages.Page):
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "<form method='post'><input type='submit'></form>"
    def render_POST(self, request):
        request.redirect("/test")
        request.finish()
        request.finish()
```

and just got two messages, one time. I still have no idea why I can't redirect the request without it saying I finished it twice (because I can't redirect without `request.finish()`).

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Hit this problem and yours was the first link in google. SO working at its best!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Short Answer

---

It has to be:

```
request.redirect("/test")
request.finish()
return twisted.web.server.NOT_DONE_YET
```

### Long Answer

---

I decided to go sifting through some Twisted source code. I first added a traceback to the area that prints the error if `request.finish()` is called twice:

```
def finish(self):
    import traceback #here
    """
    Indicate that all response data has been written to this L{Request}.
    """
    if self._disconnected:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "Request.finish called on a request after its connection was lost; "
            "use Request.notifyFinish to keep track of this.")
    if self.finished:
        warnings.warn("Warning! request.finish called twice.", stacklevel=2)
        traceback.print_stack() #here
        return
    #....
```

```
...
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\server.py", line 200, in render
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 904, in finish
    traceback.print_stack()
```

I went in and checked out `render` in `twisted.web.server` and found this:

```
    if body == NOT_DONE_YET:
        return
    if type(body) is not types.StringType:
        body = resource.ErrorPage(
            http.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            "Request did not return a string",
            "Request: " + html.PRE(reflect.safe_repr(self)) + "<br />" +
            "Resource: " + html.PRE(reflect.safe_repr(resrc)) + "<br />" +
            "Value: " + html.PRE(reflect.safe_repr(body))).render(self)

    if self.method == "HEAD":
        if len(body) > 0:
            # This is a Bad Thing (RFC 2616, 9.4)
            log.msg("Warning: HEAD request %s for resource %s is"
                    " returning a message body."
                    "  I think I'll eat it."
                    % (self, resrc))
            self.setHeader('content-length', str(len(body)))
        self.write('')
    else:
        self.setHeader('content-length', str(len(body)))
        self.write(body)
    self.finish()
```

`body` is the result of rendering a resource, so once `body` is populated, in the example case given in my question, `finish` has already been called on this request object (since `self` is passed from this method to the resource's render method).

From looking at this code it becomes apparent that by returning `NOT_DONE_YET` I would avoid the warning.

I could have also changed the last line of that method to:

```
if not self.finished:
    self.finish()
```

but, in the interest of not modifying the library, the short answer is:

after calling `request.redirect()` you must call `request.finish()` and then `return twisted.web.server.NOT_DONE_YET`

### More

---

I found some [documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html#auto6) about this. It isn't related to redirecting a request, but instead rendering a resource, using `request.write()`. It says to call `request.finish()` and then return `NOT_DONE_YET`. From looking at the code in `render()` I can see why that is the case.